# How to create excel files and then read the files through dataframe?

Tags: python

I have 20 symbols for which I need to record tick data continuously for 6 hours a day every week.
So I want 20 excel files to be created automatically by the module (if files don't exist) and a excel writer which stores tick data (row by row). Then I need to resample the data to 5 minutes timeframe after reading them through dataframe. Dataframe should be able to read the tick data created by the module.

What best excel writer can be used for this function. I want to write to the files when they are closed.

which of them will work better?

1. In built open function
2. Openpyxl
3. Xlwt

Comment: Software library suggestions are off topic for this site. But for clarification, do you really need an excel file or would a CSV (comma separated values) or TSV (tab separated values) work?

Answer (score 0):

hello i would recommed you xlwings. as it is the best module to stream the tick data to excel when file is opened.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Python's CSV Module for this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html